# Plastic stuck in laptop fan

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, fan

[image]

There seems to be a piece of plastic sticking out in my laptop fan. Is this a manufacturer error?

Comment: Can you remove it?

Comment: It likely is just foreign foreign debris.  You should remove it.  Be sure the device is turned off before you attempt this action.